# Parsing a html file using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have this html file:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Text1  
        Text2
        <a href="XYCL7Q.html">
            Text3 
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to collect separately Text1,Text2 and Text3. For Text3 I have no problems, but I am not able to capture Text1-2; by doing this:

```
 from urllib import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 url = 'myUrl';
 html = urlopen(url).read()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
 soup.body.get_text()
```

I get the all texts (first problem since I get Text3 again) not well separated since Text1-2 might contain some spaces...For instance, if Text1 is "hello world" and Text2 "foo bar", at the end I want a list of 2 strings:

```
 results = ['hello world', 'foo bar']
```

How can I do that? Thank you for the answers...

Answer (score 0):

The text you want is the first child node of "body". You can pull it out and strip off the crud

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> soup=bs("""<html>
...     <head></head>
...     <body>
...         Text1  
...         Text2
...         <a href="XYCL7Q.html">
...             Text3 
...         </a>
...     </body>
... </html>""")
...
>>> body=soup.find('body')
>>> type(next(body.children))
<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
>>> next(body.children)
u'\n        Text1  \n        Text2\n        '
>>> [stripped for stripped in (item.strip() for item in next(body.children).split('\n')) if stripped]
[u'Text1', u'Text2']
```